# Does the law of pi tikrah apply to temporary structures such as a sukkah?

Tags: talmud-bavli, sukkah, sukkot, maseches-eruvin, halacha-lemoshe-misinai

In [Eruvin 94b](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.94a?lang=bi) the Sages are debating about the Sinaitic law of partitions, more specifically “pi tikrah” ( פי תקרה יורד וסותם .) Here the topic is about permanent homes. Presently, I am in the process of Sukkos preparation and only have the schach “prepared.” This is my first foray into building this structure and am thoroughly enjoying this experience. I am curious if anyone is knowledgable about whether “pi tikrah” can be applied to a temporary structure with a slanted roof?

I am aware that Halacha states that “ pi tikrah “ would apply to the flat roof of a house, but what about a sukkah with a slanted roof?

Comment: See Sukkah 18a at the end of the amud